Dynamic function name in macro in rust langauage
I would like to create macro which will create function with name depended on input. Currently I have macro with static name "print_field".
#[allow(dead_code)]

struct Test {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}

macro_rules! create_fn {
  ($field_name:ident) => {
        fn print_field() -> () {
          let test = Test{
              a: String::from("a"),
              b: String::from("b"),
          };
          println!("The field value: {}", test.$field_name);
        }
    }
}
   
fn main() {
    create_fn!(a);
    print_field();
}

However I would like to have an option to run one macro to create two different functions:
fn main() {
    create_fn!(a);
    create_fn!(b);
    print_a();
    print_b();
}

